# Sequential continuity for quotient spaces

Tags: general-topology

Sequential continuity is equivalent to continuity in a first countable space $X$. Look at the quotient projection $g:X\to Y$ to the space of equivalence classes of an equivalence relation with the quotient topology and a map $f:Y\to Z$. I want to test if $f$ is continuous.

Can I do this by showing $$\lim_n\;f(g(x_n))=f(g(\lim_n\;x_n))\;?$$ Can I do this at least if $X$ is a metric space? Can I do this by showing $$\lim_n\;f(g(x_n))=f(\lim_n\;g(x_n))\;?$$

Comment: Note that in non-Hausdorff spaces a sequence can have more than one limit. Therefore sometimes you can see something notations like $a \in \lim x_n$ instead of $a=\lim x_n$ and $f(\lim x_n) \subseteq \lim f(x_n)$ instead of $\lim f(x_n) = f(\lim x_n)$ in cases when you do not know that the space you work with is Hausdorff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly can’t do it in general if $X$ isn’t a [sequential space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space), i.e., one whose structure is completely determined by its convergent sequences. $X$ is sequential iff it’s the quotient of a metric space, and the composition of two quotient maps is a quotient map, so if $X$ is sequential, $Y$ is also sequential, therefore $f$ is continuous iff $\lim\limits_n\;f(y_n) = f(\lim\limits_n\;y_n)$ for every convergent sequence $\langle y_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ in $Y$.

However, you can’t always pull this back to $X$.

**Edit (24 April 2016):** Take $X=[0,1]$, and let $Y$ be the quotient obtained by identifying $0$ and $1$ to a point $p$, $g$ being the quotient map. Suppose that $f:Y\to Z$, and you want to test the continuity of $f$. For $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ let

$$x_n=\begin{cases}
\frac2{n+4},&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
\frac{n+1}{n+3},&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\;,
\end{cases}$$

so that

$$\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle=\left\langle\frac12,\frac13,\frac23,\frac14,\frac34,\frac15,\frac45,\ldots\right\rangle\;.$$

Then $\langle g(x_n):n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\rangle$ converges to $p$ in $Y$, so you need to test whether $\langle f(g(x_n)):n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\rangle$ converges to $f(p)$ in $Z$, but you can’t do this by asking whether $$\lim_n\;f(g(x_n))=f(g(\lim_n\;x_n))\;,$$ because $\langle x_n:n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\rangle$ isn’t convergent in $X$. Thus, the answer to your first question is *no* even if $X$ is metric.

(This replaces a flawed example with one that actually works, borrowed from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1756355/12042) by **Eric Wofsey**.)

**End edit.**

The answer to your second question, however, is *yes*. Let $\langle y_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ be a convergent sequence in $Y$ with limit $y$. Then there are $x_n\in X$ such that $y_n = g(x_n)$ for $n\in\omega$, so checking that $$\lim_n\;f(y_n)=f(y)$$ **is** checking that $$\lim_n\;f(g(x_n))=f(\lim_n\;g(x_n))\;.$$ Note, though, that you have to check *all* sequences in $X$, not just convergent ones.

Comment: I believe that if I understand this equality $\lim_n\;f(g(x_n))=f(g(\lim_n\;x_n))$ as equality of sets (i.e., every limit of $f(g(x_n))$ is of the form $f(g(y))$ for some limit $y$ of $x_n$ and vice-versa), then the claim works whenever $X$ is sequential. (I pointed out that $\lim x_n$ can mean a set, particularly for non-Hausdorff spaces, in my comment above.)\\I believe this is basically reformulation of what you wrote, but I wanted to mention this possible point of view.

Comment: So I was wrong in my above comment - it seems that we have only inclusion, not equality. (See the proposition from Engliking I've edited into my answer.)

Comment: @Martin: I’m sorry; I meant to mention those lemmas in response to your other comment and completely forgot to do so.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I don't see, why $x_n = n + 2^{-n}$ converges to $p$ in $Y$. Consider the set $V := \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} (k - 2^{-(k+1)}, k + 2^{k+1})$. Then $p = \mathbb{N} \subseteq V$ and $V$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ and saturated w.r.t. $g$ (i.e. $g^{-1}(g(V)) = V$) which implies that $g(V)$ is open neighborhood of $p$ in $Y$. But $x_n$ is not contained in $g(V)$ for any $n$.

Comment: @yadaddy: You are of course correct; I must have been asleep when I wrote that. I’ll think about it and either simply delete that part or find an actual example.

Comment: Here are some other examples: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756305/when-does-convergence-in-quotient-space-x-sim-induce-convergence-in-x

Answer (score 2):

[Sequential spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space) are the spaces in which closed sets are precisely the sets which are closed under limits of sequences. (I.e., $V$ is closed if and only if for every convergent sequence $v_n$ of elements of $v$ every limit of this sequence belongs to $V$, too.)

- Quotient of a sequential space is again sequential.
- A map defined on a sequential space is continuous if and only if it is sequentially continuous.
- Every first-countable (hence also every metric space) is sequential.

For a good introduction in sequential spaces, you can have a look at http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0412558. Other references from the wikipedia article might be useful too. There are also several interesting entries at this [blog](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/sequential-space/).

---

I'll include two results relevant to this question as given in Engelking's General Topology. Note that by $\lim x_{\sigma}$ he denotes the set of all limits of net (or sequence) $(x_\sigma)$. (This distinction is important only in non-Hausdorff case.)

> **Proposition 1.6.15:** A mapping $f$ of a sequential space $X$ to a \tsp $Y$ is
>   continuous if and only if $$f[{\lim x_i}] \subset \lim f(x_i)$$ for every sequence
>   $(x_i)$ in the space $X$.

This is basically sequential variation of the "net version" for arbitrary topological spaces.

> **Proposition 1.6.6:** A mapping $f$ of a topological space $X$ to a topological space $Y$ is continuous if and only if
>   $$f[{\lim\limits_{\sigma\in\Sigma} x_\sigma}] \subset \lim\limits_{\sigma\in\Sigma} f(x_\sigma)$$
>   for every net $\{x_\sigma, \sigma\in\Sigma\}$ in the space $X$.