# An asymmetry in the Galois connection between topologies and sequential convergences?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

On a set $X$ consider a relation $c \subseteq X^{\mathbb{N}} \times X$ and for $((x_n), x) \in c$ write $x_n \to_c$ x. Such a relation $c$ is a sequential convergence if (i) $x \to_c x$ for all $x \in X$ and (ii) if $x_n \to_c x$ then $x_{n_k} \to_c x$ for all subsequences $x_{n_k}$ of $x_n$. If $c$ is a sequential convergence on $X$ then $(X, c)$ is a sequential convergence space. A map $f : (X, c) \to (Y, d)$ is called continuous if $x_n \to_c x$ implies $f(x_n) \to_d f(x)$.
The sequential convergence spaces together with continuous maps as morphisms form a category **SeqConv**. Denote by **Top** the category of topological spaces.

Fix a set $X$. A topology $\tau$ on $X$ induces a sequential convergence $C(\tau)$ by $x_n \to_{C(\tau)} x : \Leftrightarrow x_n \to x$ in $\tau$. Vice versa, a sequential convergence $c$ on $X$ generates a topology $T(c)$ for which a set $A \subseteq X$ is closed if $x_n \to_c x$ for $x_n \in A$ implies $x \in A$. It is known that $(T, C)$ is a Galois connection between the sequential convergences and topologies on $X$. The image of $T$ (i.e. the fixed points of $T \circ C$) are the sequential topologies on $X$ and the image of $C$ (i.e. the fixed points of $C \circ T$) are the topological sequential convergences on $X$.
Also, the maps $T$ and $C$ transfer morphisms between **Top** and **SeqConv**. Together, this gives a concrete Galois connection between these two categories.

For a surjective map $f : X \to Y$ between sets and a seq. conv. $c$ on $X$ the quotient convergence $c_f$ on $Y$ is defined by
$y_n \to_{c_f} y :\Leftrightarrow \exists x_n \in f^{-1}(y_n), x \in f^{-1}(y): x_n \to_c x$ (Dudley, "On sequential convergence" (1964), Section 3).

The quotient of a sequential topological space is always sequential.
However, the quotient of a topological convergence space is not necessarily topological (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1756355/167838) for an example). I thought that having a Galois connection gives a one-to-one correspondence between the images of $C$ and $T$. But it seems that these images (sequential topologies and topological sequential convergences) are not "compatible" with the formation of quotients. Can some explain to me in categorical terms, why that is so? Equivalently, where is the source for this incompatibility with quotients which produces such an asymmetry?