# Lifting the convergent sequence in the quotient space

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups, homogeneous-spaces

Let $G=\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$ and $\Gamma=\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$ and $X=G/\Gamma$. (Maybe we only need $\Gamma$ to be discrete I don't know.)

Consider a convergent sequence $g_i\Gamma \to g\Gamma$. I wonder if we can rechoose the representatives of cosets (for both $g_i\Gamma$ and $g\Gamma$) so that
$$g_i\to g$$

---

For this special $G$ and $\Gamma$ I think I have a proof and here is a sketch: I need the possibly unnecessary condition that $\Gamma$ is discrete and $G/\Gamma$ is metrizable. First observe that $g_i\Gamma \to g\Gamma$ is equivalent to $g^{-1}g_i\Gamma$. We choose $\gamma_i$ to be the element in the (closed) subgroup $\Gamma$ of shortest distance to $g^{-1}g_i$, then $g^{-1}g_i \gamma_i^{-1} \to e$, or $g_i\gamma_i^{-1} \to g$. But this might be true for more general $G$ and $\Gamma$.

Comment: Are the representatives $g_i$ and $g$ of the cosets fixed?  Then this is certainly not true.  On the other hand it is plausibly true if you instead ask whether you can *choose* representatives of the cosets such that $h_i=g_ig^{-1}$ converges to $e$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks! I think you are right. Edited

Comment: @EricWofsey I noticed the other answer you gave earlier https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1756355/185631   So this is in general not sure for general quotient space. Some group properties must be used here. Do you think it is true for general topological groups/homogeneous space $G/H$?